# Gets the index of the first String that starts with the target - give wrong output

Tags: java, algorithm, match, output

This method should return the index of the first string that starts with the target.

Return -1 if no string starts with the target.

My implementations works but not covers all variations.

**Code:**

```
public int getIndex(ArrayList<String> text, String target)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int index = -1;
        boolean found = false;

        while (!found && i < text.size()) //supply condition
        {           
            for (String s : text) {
                if (s.contains(target)) {                    
                    found = true;
                } else {
                    i++;
                }

                if (found) index = i;
            }  
        }

        return index;
    }
```

**testing part:**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();
       cities.add("Chicago");
       cities.add("Houston");
       cities.add("San Jose");
       cities.add("Seattle");  
       cities.add("Denver");     

       Finder finder = new Finder();

       System.out.println(finder.getIndex(cities, "C"));
       System.out.println("Expected: 0");

       System.out.println(finder.getIndex(cities, "S"));
       System.out.println("Expected: 2");

       System.out.println(finder.getIndex(cities, "D"));
       System.out.println("Expected: 4");

       System.out.println(finder.getIndex(cities, "X"));
       System.out.println("Expected: -1");
   }
```

This code has coverage `50/50` **input:**

```
  4
- Expected: 0
  3
- Expected: 2
  4
+ Expected: 4
  -1
+ Expected: -1
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Now I understand that easily this is: throw `for-each` loop, and change `if` to `if (text.get(i).startsWith(target))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You claim:

> My implementations works

It doesn't look like it to me, based on the tests. Your code is much more complicated than it needs to be, which is making it hard to find the bug. The problem is that you've got two loops for no reason:

```
while (!found && i < text.size()) //supply condition
{           
    for (String s : text) {
    }
}
```

Why have you got both of those loops? You're incrementing `i` multiple times within the inner loop...

You'd probably find it easier to get all the tests to pass if you simplify it:

```
public int getIndex(List<String> text, String target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++) {
        if (text.get(i).startsWith(target)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This is one of those cases where a dogmatic insistence on only having one `return` statement per method leads to much messier code.

Note that I've changed the condition from `contains` (in your code) to `startsWith` to match the description. You should add a test for this difference - try to find a string which is *present* in one of the cities, but the city doesn't *start* with that value.

I've also changed the parameter type to `List<String>` as you don't really need it to be an `ArrayList<String>`. (With a bit of work you could make it accept `Iterable<String>` instead, but that would be more complicated.)

I'd also recommend that you start using JUnit or something similar for your testing, rather than just using `System.out.println`.

EDIT: Just for a bit of fun, a version which takes `Iterable<String>` and uses that to handle even `LinkedList<String>` efficiently:

```
public int getIndex(Iterable<String> elements, String target) {
    int index = 0;
    for (String element : elements) {
        if (element.startsWith(target)) {
            return index;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

(Not that much harder after all...)

Comment: I wouldn't really recommend `List` for the function as is - `LinkedList#get`, for example, is not O(1), so it could become a bit of a bottleneck.

Comment: @Dukeling: It would still work correctly, but wouldn't be terribly efficient. I think that's probably okay - it's more of a design flaw in the collections library than anything else IMO. `List` becomes pretty useless if you can't treat `get` as being *reasonably* efficient.

Comment: @Dukeling: But your comment provoked me to add the more efficient and general version at the bottom :)

Comment: For interest sake, [using only a single return statement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17492335/1711796) isn't really much messier, it adds one line and an extra condition (not that I'm particularly for it).

Comment: @Dukeling: It's not *much* messier - but when the benefit of single-return is meant to be that it's *clearer*, I still think this is a good example of the opposite :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public int getIndex(ArrayList<String> text, String target)
    {

        for(int i=0;i < text.size();i++) 
        {           
           if(text.get(i).indexOf(target) == 0)
                return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: or you can use `text.get(i).startsWith(target)` instead of `text.get(i).indexOf(target)==0`

Answer (score 1):

Making the following changes:

- Get rid of unnecessary `found` variable
- Replace `contains` with `startsWith`
- Remove the `for`-loop, otherwise you pass through the data a few times
- Change the `while`-loop to a `for`-loop

I get to this, which [seems to work](https://ideone.com/Mc3WLK):

```
public int getIndex(ArrayList<String> text, String target)
{
    int index = -1;

    for (int i = 0; index == -1 && i < text.size(); i++)
    {
       if (text.get(i).startsWith(target))
       {
           index = i;
       }
    }

    return index;
}
```

You can of course [improve on it a lot more still](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17492101/1711796).

Answer (score 0):

Change the getIndex method with this:

```
public int getIndex(ArrayList<String> text, String target)
{
    int i = 0;         

    for (String s : text) {
        // Use startsWith if you want to check if the string starts with target...
        // Use contains if you want to check if contains target... 
        if (s.startsWith(target)) {
            return i;
         }

        i++;
    }  

    return -1;
}
```